# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined .......cant get all posts

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, mern

Problem: The web page is not loading and showing an error(below).

**Frontend part:**

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
const Read = () => {
  const [data, setdata] = useState([]);
  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/allpost", {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      }
    })
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(result => {
        console.log(result);
        setdata(result.posts);
      });
  });
  return (
    <div className="bg">
      <h2>Welcome to Confessions</h2>

      {data.map(posts => {
        return (
          <div className="confession">
            <div className="title">
              <h3>{posts.heading}</h3>
            </div>
            <div className="body">
              <p>{posts.confess} </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Read;
```

posts is an object.

**Backend part:**

```
router.get("/allpost", authenticate, async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const posts = await Post.find({});
    res.status(200).json(posts);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});
```

Unable to get data on postman also. I even cant get posts on postman...

**Postman error:**

```
{
    "stringValue": "\"allpost\"",
    "valueType": "string",
    "kind": "ObjectId",
    "value": "allpost",
    "path": "_id",
    "reason": {},
    "name": "CastError",
    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"allpost\" (type string) at path \"_id\" for model \"USER\""
}
```

ERROR on the web page:

```
Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
Read
src/components/Read.js:106
  103 | 
  104 | return (
  105 |     <div className="bg">
> 106 |         <h2>Welcome to Confessions</h2>
      | ^  107 |         
  108 |             {
  109 |                 data.map(posts=>{
View compiled
▶ 18 stack frames were collapsed.
(anonymous function)
src/components/Read.js:48
  45 |     }).then(res=>res.json())
  46 |     .then(result=>{
  47 |        console.log(result)
> 48 |         setdata(result.posts)
     | ^  49 |     })
  50 | })
  51 |
```

What's the correct way to write the .map function for the object.

**Please help, it's been a whole day with this problem.**

Comment: The error means that `data` is `undefined`.

Comment: Put a breakpoint on `setdata(result.posts)`. When it triggers, look at what `result` is. It probably doesn't have a `posts` property, but you'll be able to see what it *does* have and handle it accordingly. See also: [*How to debug small programs*](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: If that's the response from your server-side code then you may have noticed that response doesn't have a `posts` property.  Did you read the response?  Because it looks like an error you might want to look into resolving.  To fix the problem with `.map()` you would just set the state to an empty array instead of an `undefined` value, but that won't correct the underlying problem here.

Comment: _"Unable to get data on postman also"_ - Postman tells you what the problem is: `Cast to ObjectId failed for value "allpost" (type string) at path "_id" for model "USER"`. Did you fix that part already?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your endpoint is inside a router so it'll get prefixed with whatever you prefixed it inside your server.js/index.js as it is commonly named on the backend.

You are trying to fetch data from /allpost but i suspect the endpoint might be a bit different.

A look at your server entry point where you initialize your express app would help identify the underlying cause for this error.

Answer (score 0):

I will just address your client side error in my answer. The server side error ( `Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"allpost\"`) is the initial cause of your problem, but you also write your client side code so that it will handle error responses from the backend api without crashing.

When using the fetch api, 400 and 500 responses will not throw an error (result in a rejected promise). You have to do that yourself by checking the `response.ok` property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch#checking_that_the_fetch_was_successful

In your case, the api error will return a HTTP response with a 500 status code (error) and a valid json body. So your `res.json()` works fine.

```
useEffect(() => {
  fetch('/allpost', {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      }
    }).then(response => {
      // A 400 or 500 response from the server should throw an error.
      if (response.ok) return response.json()
      else throw new Error('Server error: ' + response.text())
    })
    .then(result => {
      // This function will only run if the previous step did not throw an error
      console.log(result)
      setdata(result.posts)
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Add error handlers in `Read.js` file

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

const Read = () => {
  const [data, setdata] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/allpost", {
      headers: {
        Accept: "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
    })
      .then((res) => res.json())
      .then((result) => {
        console.log(result);
        setdata(result.posts);
      });
  });

  return (
    <div className="bg">
      <h2>Welcome to Confessions</h2>

      {data && data.length
        ? data.map((posts) => {
            return (
              <div className="confession">
                <div className="title">
                  <h3>{posts.heading}</h3>
                </div>
                <div className="body">
                  <p>{posts.confess} </p>
                </div>
              </div>
            );
          })
        : null}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Read;
```